# Why does avcodec_fill_audio_frame return -22 when only sample count is different?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encode, pcm, libavcodec

My problem is very fast to explain: I have to encode audio samples using FFmpeg (raw PCM to G.711 mu-law). This is the guilty part of my code (I put raw parameters in this example to be explicit):

```
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
frame->nb_samples = 8000;
frame->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
frame->channels = 1;
frame->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
frame->sample_rate = 8000;
frame->quality = 1;

int res = avcodec_fill_audio_frame(frame, 1, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, /*my samples data*/, 16000, 0);

// If res >= 0, continue with avcodec_encode_audio2
```

And it works :) ... Well, I mean...

When my input is *8000* audio samples (*S16* format so *16000* bytes), it works. But when I have *6000* audio samples (still *S16* format so *12000* bytes), it fails with a -22 (invalid parameters). Any idea?

**PRECISION:** This sample count is not dynamically changing. I have sessions with data always composed by 8000 sample (and it works), and other sessions with data always composed by 6000 sample (and it fails). Sample count and data size are the only parameters that are not the same between these sessions.

**EDIT:** If I set or not the `frame_size` field in `AVCodecContext`, it returns to 0 after `avcodec_open2` but the mu-law encoder selected has the `AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE` capability so it sounds normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my own question, this was an alignment issue. There is two ways to solve it:

- Giving input buffer initialized and filled according to the default alignment desired by `libavcodec`. You can use `av_samples_get_buffer_size` with the alignment value to *0* get the proper size.
- Calling `avcodec_fill_audio_frame` with the alignment param to *1* to ignore alignment.

Hope this will help someone else :)

Answer (score 3):

The input to each call to `avcodec_encode_audio2()` should be exactly N samples, where N is [`AVCodecContext::frame_size`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#aec57f0d859a6df8b479cd93ca3a44a33). In some cases this depends on the codec (e.g. mp3 frame size is constant), but in other cases it can be variable. It should still be constant in an encoding for most encoders. It looks like your value is just whatever the default was and mulaw has no built-in constant, so you can just specify a different `frame_size` value before calling `avcodec_open2()` and you should be OK.

If your number of samples chnages dynamically, you need a ring buffer to make sure the input to `avcodec_encode_audio2()` still has a constant number of samples.

Comment: I tried to specify `AVCodecContext`'s `frame_size` before `avcodec_open2` but it didn't fix it. The field `frame_size` **is always** equal to 0 after `avcodec_open2` call, so I don't think that the encoder need that (but not sure).

Comment: Furthermore, the mu-law codec selected has the `AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE` capability.