# Convert audio samples to AVFrame FFmpeg & C++

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, ffmpeg, capture

I really need help with correcting a method that I currently work on. The method should convert and write samples into ac3 file.

Input samples are BYTE* in AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT format

For encoder the samples must have AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP format

```
bool AddAudioSample(AVFormatContext * pFormatContext, AVStream * pStream, BYTE * audiodata, uint32_t sampleCount, uint64_t devicets)
{
    AVCodecContext * pCodecCxt = NULL;
    bool res = true;

    pCodecCxt = pStream->codec;

    AVFrame*  pFLTAudioFrame = NULL;
    pFLTAudioFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    AVFrame*  pFLTPAudioFrame = NULL;
    pFLTPAudioFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    ProcessData(pFLTAudioFrame, pFLTPAudioFrame, (uint8_t *)audiodata, sampleCount, devicets);

    swr_convert(pSmplConvertCtx, pFLTPAudioFrame->data, pFLTPAudioFrame->nb_samples, (const uint8_t **)pFLTAudioFrame->data, pFLTAudioFrame->nb_samples);

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    pkt.stream_index = pStream->index;
    pkt.data = pAudioEncodeBuffer;
    pkt.size = pFLTPAudioFrame->pkt_size;

    int gotOutput = 0;
    auto ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(pCodecCxt, &pkt, pFLTPAudioFrame, &gotOutput);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (gotOutput)
    {
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pCodecCxt->coded_frame->pts, pCodecCxt->time_base, pStream->time_base);
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(pFormatContext, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

void ProcessData(AVFrame *inputframe, AVFrame *outputFrame, uint8_t* data, uint32_t sample_count, uint64_t device_ts)
{
    inputframe->nb_samples = sample_count;
    inputframe->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;
    inputframe->sample_rate = mWFX->nSamplesPerSec;
    inputframe->channels = mWFX->nChannels;
    inputframe->pkt_size = sample_count*mWFX->nBlockAlign;

    av_samples_fill_arrays(inputframe->data, inputframe->linesize, data, mWFX->nChannels, sample_count, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, 1);

    outputFrame->nb_samples = inputframe->nb_samples;
    outputFrame->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    outputFrame->sample_rate = inputframe->sample_rate;
    outputFrame->channels = inputframe->channels;
    outputFrame->pkt_size = sample_count*mWFX->nBlockAlign;

    av_samples_fill_arrays(outputFrame->data, outputFrame->linesize, pAudioEncodeBuffer, mWFX->nChannels, sample_count, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, 1);
}
```

Here is the context resampling setting and calculation for buffer packet:

```
    pSmplConvertCtx = swr_alloc();
    if (!pSmplConvertCtx)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate resampler context\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "in_channel_count",   pCodecCxt->channels,       0);
    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "in_sample_rate",     pCodecCxt->sample_rate,    0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(pSmplConvertCtx, "in_sample_fmt",      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT,         0);
    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "out_channel_count",  pCodecCxt->channels,       0);
    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "out_sample_rate",    pCodecCxt->sample_rate,    0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(pSmplConvertCtx, "out_sample_fmt",     pCodecCxt->sample_fmt,     0);

    if ((swr_init(pSmplConvertCtx)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the resampling context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    nSizeAudioEncodeBuffer = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, pCodecCxt->channels, pCodecCxt->sample_rate, pCodecCxt->sample_fmt, 1);
    if (pAudioEncodeBuffer == NULL)
    {
        pAudioEncodeBuffer = (uint8_t * )av_malloc(nSizeAudioEncodeBuffer);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, may be this points in a right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241185/why-does-avcodec-fill-audio-frame-return-22-when-only-sample-count-is-different I am not very familiar with the libav.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process function:

```
process_data(AVFrame *frame, uint8_t* data, uint32_t sample_count, uint64_t device_ts)
{
    int sample_size = _bit_per_sample / 8 * _channel_num;

    //wasapi time unit is 100ns,so time base is NS_PER_SEC
    frame->pts = _use_device_ts ? device_ts * 100 : av_gettime_relative();

    if(_use_device_ts == false)
        frame->pts -= (int64_t)sample_count * NS_PER_SEC / (int64_t)_sample_rate;

    frame->pkt_dts = frame->pts;
    frame->nb_samples = sample_count;
    frame->format = _fmt;
    frame->sample_rate = _sample_rate;
    frame->channels = _channel_num;
    frame->pkt_size = sample_count*sample_size;

    av_samples_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, data, _channel_num, sample_count, _fmt, 1);

    if (_on_data) _on_data(frame, _cb_extra_index);
}
```

for more details,you can follow
https://github.com/peilinok/screen-recorder

Comment: What does your output file sounds like?

Comment: I am trying to create an AVI file. It has two streams of audio and video

Comment: The video is being written correctly. I have audio problems

Comment: There is no sound in the output file.

Comment: you must make sure that,the pkt of video and audio stream has been set correctly

Comment: you need to resample the pcm from wasapi to FLTP(coz the newest ffmpeg only support fltp for now with default build).